# How to update python 3.5.2 to 3.6.2

Tags: 18.04, python3

I have python 3.5.2, and 3.6.7 installed but i need python 3.6.2 only how can i remove other versions and only get 3.6.2 on the machine

Comment: `ln -sf /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6` what is the output of `ls -lah /usr/bin/python*`?

Comment: Changing the specific version of Python that critical elements of your system require (including apt) is not recommended. You are likely to break you system quite horribly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt purge python2.x
sudo apt purge python3.x
```

As there are still a lot of packages that depend on Python2.x So you should have a close look at the packages that apt wants to remove before you let it proceed.

after that you can install your required version by

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3.6.2
```

then you can check by

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```